# Flipped image is mirrored, how do make the flipped image not mirrored?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, flip, mirror

I tried various ways to flip image 1 into image 2 and finally decided against any jquery plug ins, and did it this way. Image 2 is inserted into the "back1" image class using javascript. But now the flipped image 2 is mirror of the original image 2. How do I make it so that the flipped image is not mirrored?

Thanks in advance.

```js
wala = document.getElementsByClassName("back1"); 
wala[0].src = "https://placehold.it/300x200"; 
wala[0].style.cssFloat = "inherit";


function flip() {
    $('.cardx').toggleClass('flipped');
}
```

```css
.containerx {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid grey;
}
.cardx {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 2s;
    transition: transform 2s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

}
.cardx div {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

}
.cardx .front {
  background: url("https://placehold.it/300x200/DCF8FF/333333")
}
.cardx .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );

}
.cardx.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="containerx">
  <div class="cardx" onclick="flip()">
    <div class="front"></div>

    <div class="back"></div>
        <img class= "back1" alt="logo back" /> 
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What is the difference between "flipped" and "mirrored"?

Comment: Flipped image is like image 1 is the front image and image 2 is the back image, and the back image is rotated into view when the flip happens.

The mirrored image is image two that rotated in, which is the wrong way. looks like this.....

http://imgur.com/a/WZtNq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add scaleX(-1) to your css transform on the back element to escape the flipped image.

```
.cardx .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg ) scaleX(-1);
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg ) scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg ) scaleX(-1);
    transform: rotateY( 180deg ) scaleX(-1);

}

.cardx.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg ) scaleX(-1);
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg ) scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg ) scaleX(-1);
    transform: rotateY( 180deg ) scaleX(-1);

}
```

See updated snippet:

```js
wala = document.getElementsByClassName("back1"); 
wala[0].src = "https://placehold.it/300x200"; 
wala[0].style.cssFloat = "inherit";


function flip() {
    $('.cardx').toggleClass('flipped');
}
```

```css
.containerx {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid grey;
}
.cardx {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 2s;
    transition: transform 2s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

}
.cardx div {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

}
.cardx .front {
  background: url("https://placehold.it/300x200/DCF8FF/333333")
}
.cardx .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg ) scaleX(-1);
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg ) scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg ) scaleX(-1);
    transform: rotateY( 180deg ) scaleX(-1);

}
.cardx.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg ) scaleX(-1);
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg ) scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg ) scaleX(-1);
    transform: rotateY( 180deg ) scaleX(-1);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="containerx">
  <div class="cardx" onclick="flip()">
    <div class="front"></div>

    <div class="back"></div>
        <img class= "back1" alt="logo back" /> 
  </div>
</section>
```